# How not to copy everything to the device in every debugging session?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, debugging

My iOS app is pretty big, about 715 MB. Every time I start a debug session from Xcode, it copies the whole app to the device even though the only thing that changed was just the executable which is only about 60 MB.

Is there a way to make Xcode (or any other debugger) copy just the executable, or just the changed files instead of the whole application package?

Comment: Actually that is what it does. Unchanged resources are not recopied.

Comment: Where can I see a log of what it copies?

Comment: if you clean the build it will copy all the files otherwise it will only copy the changed files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of resources that need to be loaded an application, it would make sense to add a second targets for your application:

- The main application, containing the full set of data that you need to deliver to the store
- A development application, that only has a small subset of all the data you need and that you can use to speed up testing and development cycles.

Both targets should behave exactly the same, the only difference being the size of the resources.

Hope this helps!